# ejb invocation in virtual machines

Tags: jvm, virtual-machine, ejb-3.1

I have a scenario where on one physical machine there are two VMs running. The OS on both of them is GNU/Linux. running uname -a on it gives me the following info :

2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun May 6 04:00:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

on both VMs A & B.

I have jboss app server 7.1.1 running on both server A & B. A service running on server B calls EJBs on server A using JNDI.

However very often, I see this error :

> 13:48:27,250 ERROR [com.nlg.websched.cron.ConcurrentJobRunner] (WebScheduler_Worker-59) No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:"something",modulename:infrastructure,distinctname:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@357b544e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:"something",modulename:infrastructure,distinctname:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@357b544e
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:584) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:119) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:136) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:121) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:104) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]

Thanks!

Comment: If you have two VMs, each will not have relationship with the other more than they would have if in different physical machines (that is the point of the VM thing). If the network setup of your machines is right (you do not have IP/MAC/hostname conflict) the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: there is no conflict in the IPs associated with the two VMs. Any other pointers on where I should be looking to debug this problem ?